# How to link projects in Project References page with projects in CDT References tab

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

I would like to programmatically link projects in Project References page with the projects in C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> References Tab, see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy0hV.png). When a user checks a project in Project References page than that project in C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> References Tab is also checked. This does not have to happen immediately when a user checks the project it would be perfectly acceptable if this action is done when user clicks on OK button of the properties wizard. When I check a project in C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> References Tab and than click on Apply and OK that project is also checked in Project References page so basically I would like to achieve the same thing only in the other direction. Can somebody help me with this ?